# Python задача на массивы

Tags: python

Найти в массиве те элементы, значение которых меньше среднего арифметического, взятого от всех элементов массива.

Моя попытка решения:

```py
a = [1,7,15,4,2] 
sum = 0 
for i in range (0,len(a)):
    sum += a[i] 
sredn = sum/ len(a)
```

Comment: А где Ваши попытки решения?

Comment: a = [1,7,15,4,2]
sum = 0
for i in range (0,len(a)):
    sum += a[i]
    sredn = sum/ len(a)

Comment: а дальше не знаю

Comment: Только не называйте свою переменную `sum`, вы перекрываете встроенную функцию питона

Answer (score 2):

```
def avg(l):
    n = len(l)
    return (sum(l) / n)
```

Изначальный список значений

```
array = [1, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Найдем средние значения

```
res = avg(array)
print(res)
```

Отберем нужные значения из списка

```
array = [item for item in array if res > item]
print(array)
```